# Ошибка - Невозможно преобразовать Array в Object[][]

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите, как выгрузить в Гугл Таблицу данные, полученные с сайта в формате JSON. Ниже приведен код, но на выходе получаю ошибку **Невозможно преобразовать Array в Object[][]**. 
В режиме Отладки видно, что код работает, а ошибка возникает в последней строке resultRange.setValues(results);

```html
function processXMRAPI() 
{

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1v2NmYXtURFR3cnrhmuzrcFX48YQTLGRO8Nq4dkL4l1w');  
  
  var APIPullSheet = ss.getSheetByName ("APIPull");
  APIPullSheet.getRange('A1:M300').clearContent();

  var url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());
  
  var results = [[]];
  //results.push(['MarketName', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Last', 'BaseVolume', 'TimeStamp', 'Bid', 'Ask', 'OpenBuyOrders', 'OpenSellOrders', 'PrevDay', 'Created']);
  for(var i in parcedData.result)
    {
      results.push(parcedData.result[i]);
    }
  resultRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, 13);
  resultRange.setValues(results);
}
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
[image: Это режим отладки, стоп стоит в цикле на строке results.push(parcedData.result[i]);]

Comment: приведи пример того, что ты получаешь в `parcedData.result`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скрин отладчика.

Comment: Что за отладчик?

Comment: все, кажется понял в чем проблема, сейчас у тебя `results`  имеет вид: `[[], {},{},{}]`, а должен иметь вид: `[[...],[...],[...]]`

Comment: И как быть в данном случае, JSON сообщение мне не исправить.

Comment: так проблема как раз в том, как ты собираешь `results`. Попробуй заменить `results.push(parcedData.result[i]);` на `results[0].push(parcedData.result[i]);` и посмотреть изменится что-то или нет

Comment: Скрипт писался в Google App Script, там есть отладчик.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема ошибки была в том, что массив result не был приведен к нужному виду.

Имел такой вид `[[], {},{},{}]`, а должен иметь вид: `[[...],[...],[...]]`

После замены

```
results.push(parcedData.result[i]);
```

на

```
results[0].push(parcedData.result[i]);
```

ошибка исчезла.